# Is async/await not intended for global synchronous use?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I expect this code:

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => 
    setTimeout(() => { resolve('resolved'); }, 2000) );
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  var result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);
}

asyncCall();
asyncCall();
```

To produce this output:

```
"calling"
"resolved"
"calling"
"resolved"
```

But instead I get this:

```
 "calling"
 "calling"
 "resolved"
 "resolved"
```

I have to do this to make my code synchronous:

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => 
    setTimeout(() => { resolve('resolved'); }, 2000) );
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  var result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);
}

const main = async () => {
  await asyncCall();
  await asyncCall();
};

main();
```

This means that if I have an await call deep inside a function call tree, I have to have async/await all the way down my function chain to get synchronous behavior for my entire application? This seems very onerous to me. Please tell me I'm wrong. This definitely removes most of the good feelings around async/await for me :(

Comment: async/await doesn’t change the fact that you are working in a single non-blocking thread. So, yes, you need to use the second approach, or something similar, to get the results you expect.

Comment: async/await doesn't make anything synchronous. It is a syntax for asynchronous logic and has nothing to do with synchronous code.

Comment: It would be very problematic if the first code snippet did what you wanted it to do. There would be no way to ever initiate two or more asynchronous requests concurrently.

Comment: It would have required interpreter changes to make async functions block and not return async themselves. But it should be doable. (per Crowder below there is a stage 2 proposal for that so it IS possible).

Comment: There is a proposal to allow `await` at the module scope. There is no proposal to make async functions block. `async` functions return Promise objects; that is the whole point on them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason your first two `asyncCalls` overlap is that you don't `await` them. So the first starts the timeout, returns, and you call the second, which also starts the timeout and returns.

> Is async/await not intended for global synchronous use?

Yes and no. You can only use `await` in an `async` function (though there's a [Stage 2 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) to add top-level `await`), so (for now, anyway) you can't use `await` at global scope. But there's no reason you can't immediately switch to an `async` function, such as your `main` or even just inline:

```
(async () => {
    // Use await here...
})().catch(err => {
    // Last-ditch error handling here
});
```

or

```
(async () => {
    try {
        // Use await here...
    } catch (err) {
        // Last-ditch error handling here
    }
})();
```

Comment: There is a [stage-2 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) for top-level `await`...although that's not without it's issues.

Comment: @JaredSmith - Thanks -- that one passed me by.

Comment: @JaredSmith - Am I missing it, or is the proposal only for top-level `await` *in modules*? (Not that modules shouldn't start being our default top-level anyway...)

Comment: Yes, and one variant of the proposal is only in modules with no exports (presumably to avoid the situation of long blocking loads in the dependency graph).

Comment: Well I guess we'll have widespread use of webassembly soon which should let us use more synchronous behavior.

Comment: @MatthewB. - I don't see how webassembly would have much of anything to do with how synchronous the behavior is. I hope not, anyway, the way I see people coding busy-loop waits. :-)

Comment: @JaredSmith - Thanks again!